# strsep() with '\n' as a delimiter in C

Tags: c

So I am currently using *strsep()* to separate my string where the given string is

```
char str[] = "line 01\n"
                 "line 02\n"
                 "line 03\n"
                 "line 04\n"
                 "line 05\n"
                 "line 06\n"
                 "line 07\n"
                 "line 08\n"
                 "line 09\n"
                 "line 10\n";
```

and I am using `strsep(&str, "\n")` to separate them. So my concern is that I am actually using two delimiters "\" and "n" right? Then how do I just make the delimiter to be just "\n". Because after extracting "line 10", strsep replaces the "\" with "\0". But str[] itself is terminated by "\0", and one of my delimiters is "\" so it will actually treat that the "\" in "\0" as another string hence I would have extracted an unnecessary empty string.

Comment: The string is not terminated by `"\0"` but by a single `0`. A`'\0'` is a way to express that `0` textually as a `char`.

Comment: Please post more of your code. I don't understand what problem you're having here because `\n` is recognized as the escape sequence for a single character, in this case ASCII newline or the byte `0xa`. Likewise `\0` is the escape sequence representing the byte `0x0`.

Comment: Did you mean `char *str[]` ? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane : it's a single string — there are no commas separating the string fragments.

Comment: I don't think, if they're using `strsep`, that they intended `char *[]`. Seems they're more just confused about escape sequences.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh OK but the MCVE is still worth posting.

Comment: "*I am actually using two delimiters "\" and "n" right?*" No, why?

Comment: You should not be passing `&str` to `strsep()` because the function modifies the pointer that is passed by reference and you can't modify and array's address.  Besides, the type is wrong: you pass `char (*)[]` (with a size I can't be bothered to calculate), but the function expects a `char **` — quite different in type!

Answer (score 2):

Inside string and character literals, escape sequences are processed so that (for example) `\n` and `\0` become the *single* characters "newline" and "string terminator" - they are *not* two characters each as you seem to think.

This important detail is in `C11 5.1.1.2 Translation Phases` in phase 5:

> Each source character set member ***and escape sequence*** in character constants and string literals is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set; if there is no corresponding member, it is converted to an implementation-defined member other than the null (wide) character.

Also in `5.2.1 Character sets /2`:

> In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be represented by corresponding members of the source character set ***or by escape sequences consisting of the backslash \ followed by one or more characters.***

The actual escape sequences you are permitted to use are detailed in several places in the standard, I won't show them all here since the answer's probably already big enough.

---

However, based on a careful reading of your question, I suspect your *actual* problem is misunderstanding why separating your strings using a newline token results in an empty string after "line 10".

That can be easily understood if you consider the following string:

```
A|B|C
```

If you separate that based on `|`, you'll end up with the three values `A`, `B` and `C`. If you do the same thing to the string `A|B|`, you'll end up with `A`, `B` and the empty string.

That's almost certainly what's happening with your string. Because your last few characters are `line 10\n` and you're using `\n` as the separator, there's actually an *extra* empty string following that final `\n`.

I suspect if you take off the final newline, your problem will go away.

Comment: Because when I used a while loop to extract all the strings in str[], my loop should have returned NULL after extracting "line 10" but it kept going and further extracted an empty string

Comment: Oh ok I understand, but I was given such string, I can't modify it. The condition of the string is given such that "\n" indicates a new line and the whole str[] is terminated by "\0"

Comment: @JLe: if you're not permitted to modify it, you'll simply have to work around it. One way would be to ignore empty tokens in the string, or to figure out if this is your last token and ignore it (or maybe a combination to ignore the last token but only if it's empty). It depends a great deal on your requirements which we're not totally privy to.